# Quartus 14.1 encrypted files used in Quartus 17.1

Tags: vhdl, verilog, system-verilog, quartus

Are there any issues with using Quartus encrypted files version specific to Quartus 14.1 in Quartus prime 17.1 ?

Comment: This is not a VHDL, Verilog or SV question

Comment: Quartus is used for Verilog, SV, and VHDL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with the encryption, but the original source code. Sometimes "fixes" to the compiler breaks what you thought was working code. You have to try it yourself, or ask the originator of the encrypted code to verify it for you with the latest version.